# Free sources to learn Field theory.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, differential-algebra

I want to learn all the theories that are required to learn Differential Algebra. One of them is Field theory. I wonder if there are any free credible sources on the internet about this field where I could learn from scratch? What I found so far are basically notes and they don't seem to give a deep insight into Field theory.

Comment: What is your mathematical background?

Comment: @Kamal Milne notes in Mathematics.

Comment: @Zackkenyon I am mostly a calculus person with a bit of knowledge in Number theory

Comment: @3ibfwcbi I will check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, differentiel algebra relies heavily on Galois theory. In order to understand this, you need to know group theory and field theory first. A good reference is **Abstract Alegbra** by **Dummit & Foote** which also is about Galois theory. As for notes on Galois theory, those of **J.S. Milne** are really great and freely avalaible on internet.